# Creating a new column based on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a new column based on other columns existing in my `df`.
My new column, `col`, should be `1` if there is at least one `1` in columns A ~ E.
If all values in columns A ~ E is `0`, then value of `col` should be `0`.
I've attached image for a better understanding.

What is the most efficient way to do this with python, not using `loop`? Thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUUav.png)

Answer (score 0):

If need test all columns use  [`DataFrame.max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.max.html) or [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) with cast to integers for `True/False` to `1/0` mapping:

```
df['col'] = df.max(axis=1)
df['col'] = df.any(axis=1).astype(int)
```

Or if need test columns between `A:E` add [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df['col'] = df.loc[:, 'A':'E'].max(axis=1)
df['col'] = df.loc[:, 'A':'E'].any(axis=1).astype(int)
```

If need specify columns by list use subset:

```
cols = ['A','B','C','D','E']
df['col'] = df[cols].max(axis=1)
df['col'] = df[cols].any(axis=1).astype(int)
```

Comment: I was thinking `df['col'] = df['A':'E'].max(axis=1)` might be an option given the OP's example data

Comment: @JonClements - thanks, `loc` is not necessary?

Comment: @JonClements - Tested and your solution return `TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on RangeIndex with these indexers [A] of type str`, `loc` is necessary

Comment: yeah... it's 7am in the morning and I've been working all night... :)

Comment: @JonClements - Ou, I suggest go to bed if possible ;)